# devise with multiple layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I really like to authenticate my devise user through 2 different interfaces with a view to have 2 different layout.

For example I would be able to use /users/sign_in and /admin/sign_in based on the same User model.

I had set 2 routes :

```
devise_for :users
```

and

```
devise_for :users, :module => "admin/users", :path => ''
```

But I'm not sur it's the right way to do that because I need overwrite current_user on my application controller, like this:

```
def current_user
    super || current_admin_user
end
```

Moreover I have 2 methods : authenticate_user! and authenticate_admin_user!

I'm really confused with this specification, can anybody help ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got your problem, if not, please comment on it :)

There is no need to overwrite current_user. You can create a filter that filters admins like this:

```
def require_admin_user
  unless current_user.admin
    flash[:error] = "You need admin privileges to enter this area"
    redirect_to root_path 
  end
end
```

`current_user` will return the current_user logged in, whether it is an admin or it isn't an admin. If you want for an user to be able to login in as an admin only if they as an ordinary user, I would suggest another approach: creating another model for admins and filtering for require_user! for the admin `sign_in`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. It's not what I want...
I had a single model called user with a role (admin, student, ...). For the student user I want a login page (like /user/sign_in) with a specified designed. For the other user, I want a other login page (like /admin/sign_in) with a different design and different devise controller.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use STA (Single Table Inheritance)… Then you can use 2 `devise_for` declarations, one for each model.

Comment: that doesn't solve my problem. I can't have a model for each roles. What I need is only a differents login layout for each role.

Comment: I'm assuming you have a `role` attribute on your model… STA will give you a hierarchy of classes for different values of the `role` attribute, however, you'll still have a single table named `users`. This way you can "trick" Devise into thinking you have different models, and take advantage of that, having different sign-on controllers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
I have a different controller admin in that i have added a login action.

 class AdminController < ApplicationController   
    def login
      @user = User.new
    end
  end

In view of login.html.erb

<%= form_for(@user, :as => :user, :url => session_path(:user)) do |f| %>
<% end %>


U can now call admin/login path

 and successfully got sign up, but if you want to redirect to some other page after sign up instead of root url then

In application controller write inside this method of devise

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
 end
```